# Как вывести данные с двух таблиц?

Tags: delphi-7, sql

Здравствуйте, вопрос по Delphi7, столкнулся со следующим. Есть две таблицы, с полями:

- 1 таблица ( модель, группа, кол-во).
- 2 таблица (завод, номер).

Как через SQL запрос, в DBGrid вывести данные в таком виде

> модель, кол-во, завод

Comment: А по каким полям первая таблица объединяется со второй?

Comment: простите забыл написать, во второй есть поле id_gruppa которое связано с полем группа в первой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем список полей первого источника данных. Если там пусто, то создаем этот список через контекстное меню "Add all fields"

Далее создаем новое поле "New Field".

[image]

В диалоге заполняем название поля "Name", тип поля для отображения "Type", в "Field Type" выбираем "Lookup", в "KeyFields" выбираем ключевое поле для связки из первого источника данных, в "Dataset" выбираем второй источник данных, в "Lookup Keys" выбираем ключевое поле второй таблицы, а в "Result Field" - поле второй таблицы для отображения.

На выходе, в первом источнике данных, имеем поле которое выбирается из второго. Как одна из приятных плюшек такого связывания - это то, что в гриде это поле можно редактировать как выпадающий список.